# Mysql ignora my.cnf al instalar cacti

Tags: mysql, centos

Tengo instalado mysql 5.5.58 sobre centos 6.9 en el cual tengo pensado montar cacti para monitorear mi red, tengo instalado php 5.4.45 y apache 2.4 el problema es que al comenzar el proceso de instalación cacti, el asistente me señala que debo hacer algunas modificaciones en el archivo my.cnf que esta dentro de /etc/my.cnf, el problema es que hago los cambios mencionados pero mysql al parecer no parece tomarlos en cuenta ya que el instalador de cacti me sigue mostrando que los cambios no han sido llevado a cabo, busque por que pasaba esto y al parecer mysql ignora los cambios efectuados en los archivos que tienen permisos de escrituras de alguna manera me di cuenta que los permisos fueron modificados y tenia permisos 777 y recomendaba modificarlos a 644, realice esta modificación pero mysql sigue sin tomar en cuenta las nuevas configuraciones. mi archivo my.cnf es el siguiente.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

symbolic-links=0
#Semisynchronous Replication
#http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html
#uncomment next line on MASTER
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_master=semisync_master.so
#uncomment next line on SLAVE
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_slave=semisync_slave.so

#Other options for Semisynchronous Replication
;rpl_semi_sync_master_enable=1
;rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=10
;rpl_semi_sync_slave_enable=1

#http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance/-schema.html
;performance_schema

[mysqld safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

#Cacti configurations
max_heap_table_size = 100M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
tmp_table_size = 64M
innobd_file_per_table = ON
innobd_buffer_pool_size = 450M
innobd_doublewrite = OFF
innobd_additional_mem_pool_size = 80M

#include all files rom the config directory
!include etc/my.cnf.d
```

Comment: ¿Reiniciaste el servicio de MySQL para que tomara los cambios?

Comment: reiniciaste MySQL?, con un 'service mysql restart' en terminal bastará.

Comment: @sustentio Si así es reinicio el servicio mysqld incluso reinicio httpd también pero aun así no reconoce las modificaciones he intentado modificar las variables c¡globales directamente desde la consola de mysql utilizando _set global_ y he podido ver que las modificaciones son llevadas a cabo pero al reiniciar el servicio vuelve a tomar sus valores originales. como puedo saber a que archivo apunta en este caso cacti saber cual es la ruta del archivo my.cnf que esta tomando en cuenta?

Comment: @YeisonH.Arias claro amigo pero no he logrado hacer que se vean reflejados los nuevos valores de mi variables globales

Comment: Al parecer el problema radica en que debí haber instalado mariadb en lugar de mysql, he echo una nueva instalación y pero con mariadb y todo funciona perfectamente. aun que no se a que se deba pude solucionar mi problema remplazando mysql por mariadb.